# Camera is being rotated 90 degree in air for android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, camera, rotation

In my AS3 Flex Mobile application for Android, I am using camera and it is being automatically rotated 90 degrees before I even done any video rotation by myself, it seems like it's a known bug in AIR. But I was wondering if anyone found a solution since it's really pretty important feature for mobile application developer.

I've tried to do some rotation manually in my code, but it is only fixes the view on my display, but still sends the wrong video to the receiver.

If any code is required I will add the snippets

Please let me know.

Comment: This could be your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35657156/adobe-air-cameraui-photo-orientation

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, this is a known bug with AIR. It is not consistent, either. On some devices, it is in the correct orientation but in some (and all iOS devices, I believe, though I haven't fully tested that), it is rotated as you are seeing. For example, it was always oriented correctly on my Nexus 4 and on my Nexus 5, but a friends Moto X is rotated incorrectly.

Unfortunately, I don't believe there is anything you can do short of having the user do a calibration (i.e. overlay a straight line and tell them to place it horizontally and click a button) and rotating the camera display and any images you take with the display.

That being said, if you are using the camera to take photos, I highly recommend using `CameraUI` instead, which is the native implementation.

Comment: Ah, thanks for response, it's getting pretty messy, so I can't even tell which device is going to display video correctly and which not.

Comment: @Stanislav Unfortunately, no. As I said, it is a known bug in AIR that predominantly affects iOS and affects a minor subset of Android devices as well. Something to do with AIR not reading the default camera orientation correctly. Not much you can do, unfortunately, unless you want to build the calibration test I suggested or switch to `CameraUI`

Comment: so you are saying to change all the Camera classes instances to CameraUI? are those even similar classes? I am new to as3 and air, so I am not quite sure how much it's going to take to change everything, and the biggest question, will this actually solve the rotation problem?

Comment: Create a test project and create a `CameraUI` instance and see for yourself. It will only work on-device, however. It is the native way to take photos and video. It is **not** a `DisplayObject` and will cover your entire app while it is active. It will ensure it is oriented properly, however.

Comment: is there a way to use CameraUI to transmit the video ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I wasn't aware of your intentions here. On images, EXIF data contains a rotation property which you can use to auto-correct the image (I do it for several PHP-based sites that accept uploads from AIR apps). Figure out the video format you are transmitting and see if there is a similar property.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue today but i'm developping in Java, not with AIR so i don't know if it the same, for me the solution was to add this line before starting the recording.

```
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the is no such a thing as setOrientationHint() in Air